# Disable zoom controls on a mapview in Titanium

Tags: mkmapview, titanium, android-mapview, titanium-mobile

I'm working with a mapview in Titanium and I want to disable the zoom controls, which property  should I modify?

Answer (score 1):

If you won't let the User interact with the Map then a Mapview isn't the correct choice I guess.
What you want is maybe a ImageView with a StaticMap file in it.
-> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=de

Answer (score 0):

Just place a transparent view in front of it, which will intercept any touch gestures.